# Difference between Ctrl-C and kill -INT?

Tags: bash, shell-script, kill, signals

I have a signal handler in C++ program:

```
void term(int signum)
{
    cout << "in term" << endl;
    # Do Stuff
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    # Do Stuff
    signal(SIGINT, term);
    # Do Stuff
}
```

The program works fine. goes in the function term when I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and exits.

However, when I try to replicate the behavior using a script, it does not work.

Simplified version of the script I am running:

```
! /bin/bash
sudo ./program &
rpid=$!

sleep 2
sudo kill -INT $rpid
# sudo kill -TERM $rpid
# sudo kill $rpid

echo "killed"
wait $rpid
```

The program is does not even go in the term function until I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.
It is stuck on wait indefinitely.

Comment: The title asks about the difference between Ctrl-C and `kill -INT`? The body is about the difference between C and a shell script. OR did I miss-read it (In which case it is confusing).

Comment: Even in those small snippets you're doing a lot of dubious things like __a)__ use iostreams in signal handlers __b)__ calling `exit(3)` from a signal handler __c)__ using `signal()` (which _nobody_ actually knows how it works) instead of `sigaction(2)` __d)__ pointlessly using `sudo`, etc. Please submit a reproducible example.

Comment: First you can not (normally) send signals to a process running as root, when not root. And second you can not ctrl-C a process that is running as a background job.

Comment: @Mosvy OK so I miss-read it. The problem with the question is that it took two reading. There is a bit where is tells the reader that it is about to show a shell script alternative to the C program. But then we realise that it is an alternative to the manual operation. Well it is ambiguous, so half of readers will go one way, and half the other, on first reading.

Comment: you _cannot_ use iostreams or stdio functions inside signal handlers. Replace it with `write(1, "in term\n", 8);` Anyways, try submitting a complete reproducible example.

Comment: It compiles in c++11. Why we cannot use iostream in signal handler?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the problem is that Ctrl-C will send a `SIGINT` signal to the entire process group (job), while `kill -INT $!` will only send it to the process group leader. If `sudo` is actually _waiting_ for the command it runs (I have no idea whether that's the case), only `sudo` will be killed, not the child it waits for.

Comment: @NofelYaseen because the iostream functions are not signal safe, read `man signal-safety`

Comment: iostream is only present to test if the program goes in the function or not. That is not relevant to the problem. I removed sudo from the program and it works. Any reason why is this case? I still want to run the program as sudo, considering I am sending the signal as sudo.

Comment: Related: [How can bash script do the equivalent of Ctrl-C to a background task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696427/how-can-bash-script-do-the-equivalent-of-ctrl-c-to-a-background-task). Key finding: "Thus, when you run a background process (with &) from within a script, it will ignore the SIGINT signal, unless it is trapped. " So `sudo` is ignoring SIGINT, and your `./program`, a child of sudo,  cannot undo that.

Comment: @NofelYaseen 1. yes, it is perfectly relevant; if you call unsafe funcs from signal handlers, _anything_ could happen. 2. please read my comment above -- you should send the signal to the whole process group. `kill -INT -$!` (with the negated pid) may work, but nobody really knows as long as you don't submit a reproducible testcase.

Comment: @mosvy I meant irrelevant in the sense, if I remove the line, it still does not work. The answer written and Mark's comment made me understand that I need to get pid of the child to make it work. Thanks everyone!

Comment: No, you don't need the child of the pid -- you can kill the whole process group, just as Ctrl-C does, by using the negated pid of the process group leader, see the `kill(2)` manpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% sudo sh -c 'exec echo My process ID is $$.' & echo "Xyr process ID is $\!." ; wait
[1] 59130
Xyr process ID is 59130.
My process ID is 59131.
[1]  + done       sudo sh -c 'exec echo My process ID is $$.'
%
```

Welcome to the world of Pluggable Authentication Modules!  Programs like `login`, `su`, and `sudo` do not overlay themselves with the target program any more.

You are sending your signals to the wrong process.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014).  ["PAM changed everything, over two decades ago."](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html#PAM). *Don't abuse su for dropping user privileges*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- [How to sudo + exec?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/529348/5132)